# Passing Environment variables to a jq command

Tags: bash, shell, jq

This works

```
jq -s   '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"RobsMSP":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ./channel-artifacts/${ORG_NAME}.json > modified_config.json
```

This doesn't work

```
ORG_NAME="Robs"
jq -s --arg ORG "${ORG_NAME}MSP"  '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"$ORG":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ./channel-artifacts/${ORG_NAME}.json > modified_config.json
```

I have looked at other stackoverflow pages regarding a similar issue and have tried env.ORG_NAME but nothing seems to do what I'm asking. I just want to pass ORG_NAME from my environment, append "MSP" to the end of "ORG_NAME" and then pass that to my jq command.`enter code here`

Comment: FYI, that's a shell variable, not an environment variable. It only becomes an environment variable if you do `export ORG_NAME`.

Comment: `"$ORG"` should be `($ORG)`

Comment: I tried jq -s --arg ORG "${ORG_NAME}MSP"  '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"($ORG)":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ./channel-artifacts/${ORG_NAME}.json > modified_config.json                                                           and got ******************************* jq -s --arg ORG RobsMSP '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Application":{"groups": {"($ORG)":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ./channel-artifacts/Robs.json  back from my termianl meaning that the arg ORG was still not being called correctly.

Comment: Don't put `($ORG)` in double quotes. That prevents expanding the variable.

Comment: Did you read the linked question, it shows exactly how to do it?